# cat output different to vi output

Tags: unix, vim, utf-8, cat

When I cat a file it shows

```
"dest_info_s": "B\u001e�����"
```

When I vi into it, it shows:

```
"dest_info_s": "B\u001eøøïùÄ"
```

I assume this is due to the way the file is encoded and vi is doing some conversion that cat is unable to do?
How do I remove the encoding on the file so that it just displays as text?
The reason I want to remove the encoding is because sed does not work correctly on the file to do the replace as it compares the text in the sed command to the encoded text and doesn't get a match.

Comment: You'll need to adjust your terminal.  It expects UTF-8, but the data isn't in UTF-8 (it's probably ISO 8859-1).  Or you'll need to fix your data.  The characters have codes 0xF8 (twice), 0xEF, 0xF9, 0xC4 — of which 0xF8 and 0xF9 are unconditionally invalid in UTF-8, and the other two require continuation bytes to be valid UTF-8 (0xC4 requires one continuation byte; 0xEF requires two continuation bytes).  I'm not entirely sure why/how `vim` gets the encoding right, but `cat` sends the raw bytes to your terminal and the display is your terminal saying "I don't like that".

Answer (score 4):

Regardless where it's stored or on what display device it's printed, all text must be encoded using one encoding or another. It's impossible to "remove the encoding" from a text file. All you can do is convert the text from its source encoding to a destination encoding. The encoding of a piece of text is like energy: you can't create or destroy it, all you can do is convert it from one form to another.

The graphemes that are rendered when a piece of text is printed depend on (1) the encoding of the text, (2) the program that prints the text (specifically, whether it does any encoding conversion before passing the data to the display device), and (3) the configuration and font support of the display device that is actually responsible for rendering the text. In your case, we're talking about (1) the encoding of your text file, (2) cat and vim, and (3) your virtual terminal.

The cat utility is mostly not text-aware, and never does any text encoding conversion; it basically just copies the bytes it receives from its input sources to its stdout.

Assuming you're not using a very old version of vim, it dynamically detects the encoding of the file and captures that in the [`'fileencoding'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'fileencoding') setting (note: for this detection, it only tries the encodings specified in [`'fileencodings'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'fileencodings')), uses [`'encoding'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'encoding') for its internal storage encoding (not relevant for our purposes), and uses [`'termencoding'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'termencoding') when interpreting keyboard input and when printing text to the terminal.

Based on your sample output, I'm guessing that your text file is a one-byte-per-character encoding, possibly latin1, and your terminal is configured to use UTF-8 encoding. That's why the cat output renders the final 5 bytes as [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER U+FFFD �](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character). Those 5 bytes represent non-ASCII characters, and are thus not valid UTF-8. When you see the U+FFFD grapheme, your terminal is telling you that you've sent it invalid UTF-8. (Note: Sometimes terminals use [MEDIUM SHADE U+2592 ▒](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Block_Elements) instead of U+FFFD for bytes that are invalid UTF-8, and sometimes you'll see different graphemes rendered for valid UTF-8 characters that are not supported by the display device's font; see https://www.quora.com/What-symbol-is-the-square-box-shown-for-non-representable-Unicode-characters.)

But it looks like vim is correctly recognizing the file encoding, and its idea of the terminal encoding is also correct. Thus, when it prints the file content to the terminal, it's correctly translating between the source encoding bytes and the corresponding UTF-8 representation. Thus the 5 non-ASCII characters are showing up correctly, as the correct graphemes.

If my above inferences are correct, you don't need to change any settings; cat, vim, and your terminal are all behaving correctly.

If you want to be able to print the file content to your terminal manually, without depending on vim, you can use the `iconv` program to perform the necessary conversion. Something like this (assuming latin1 is the source encoding):

```
iconv -f latin1 -t UTF-8 file.txt;
```

It's generally advisable to try to work with UTF-8 at all times. I'm not sure why your sed command is not working (that depends on the details of your sed command, which you haven't provided), but you can likely get it working by storing the UTF-8-encoded version of the file somewhere, and then run the sed command on that:

```
iconv -f latin1 -t UTF-8 file.txt >file-utf8.txt;
sed '...' file-utf8.txt;
```

Or, you can use a pipeline to do it in one go:

```
iconv -f latin1 -t UTF-8 file.txt| sed '...';
```

Answer (score 2):

`cat` is dumb - It just echos the response to your terminal. If your terminal doesn't understand the bytes it's receiving, your terminal (not cat) may choose to render those characters as "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER U+FFFD" (�), or the bytes may match the incorrect points in the terminal's encoding. If your terminal encoding matches the encoding of the file, then you'll be in luck.

Although it won't help cat, you should always ensure that your locale matches your terminal emulation. This helps tools like vi to make the appropriate translation between screen and file.

For example, my terminal emulation is set to `UTF-8` and my locale is `en_GB.UTF-8`. Use the `LANG` environment to change your locale.